# Can you manage SSIS packages through a custom-built web front-end?

Tags: ssis

I want to set up a custom-built web application/portal which allows users to manage their own SSIS packages (connections, flows, and data sources). Is there an API built in, or the ability to create one?

I have a lot of experience with SSRS and know that you can build custom web front-ends for report management. Haven't been able to unearth any good information or examples for SSIS.

Comment: I have done this before. Our system used the SSISDB for deployment. Which you can then use the [SSISDB catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/deploy-and-execute-ssis-packages-using-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-2014) to execute the packages via the front end. It worked out fairly well. We even tied in the error logs so the user could troubleshoot on their own executions. Data sources/connections can be stored in the SSISDB and modified through sprocs, so that would work for you as well.

Comment: Ahhh! So, in theory, I could write stored procedures which allow a user to create their own projects, identify data sources, create flows, and have them output to a table? Then they'd be able to call these sprocs from a front end...? Well hot dog... :D

Comment: @RyanAnderson are you asking for building package using api or just managing existing packages?

Comment: @Hadi I want the user to be able to build a package - select their own data sources (flat files, DB connections) and export it into their designated SSAS instance. In theory, they could manage their own packages too.

Comment: @RyanAnderson if you meant that users can built packages via graphical user interface (SSDT) i don't think it can be done. You can instead use wrapper classes such as Ezapi or DTS assemblies to implement you own logic using C#/VB.Net

Comment: Sorry! I misunderstood. You can only manipulate the package executions, parameters, connections, etc. via SSISDB. Not create the packages themselves, though. That would be an interesting idea, as they are simply XML files. But maybe quite a task to duplicate in a browser. The documentation for the specification is [over 500 pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_data_portability/ms-dtsx/235600e9-0c13-4b5b-a388-aa3c65aec1dd). I wouldn't say impossible, but certainly a significant effort.